# How to have different settings.py locally and in production

Tags: python, django, heroku

I want to have different settings.py for when I run my project locally and in production, because I have a setting in settings.py that forces my project to use https, but django runserver.py can only use http, not https, so I am unable to run my project locally now. Also, I want to have debug=True on my computer, and debug=False in production. So how can I have a different settings.py for my computer and for production?

Comment: I recommend using Git for this, create two branch development and production, keep your settings in these separate branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some options, one these to create two settings files:

add the following **to the end** of your **settings.py**:

```
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
PROJECT_APP_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
PROJECT_APP = os.path.basename(PROJECT_APP_PATH)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_APP_PATH)

DEBUG = False
...

...

##################
# LOCAL SETTINGS #
##################

# Allow any settings to be defined in local_settings.py which should be
# ignored in your version control system allowing for settings to be
# defined per machine.

f = os.path.join(PROJECT_APP_PATH, "local_settings.py")
if os.path.exists(f):
    import sys
    import imp
    module_name = "%s.local_settings" % PROJECT_APP
    module = imp.new_module(module_name)
    module.__file__ = f
    sys.modules[module_name] = module
    exec(open(f, "rb").read())
```

Create **local_settings.py** and overwrite the desired settings:

```
#####################
# OVERWRITE SETTINGS #
#####################

DEBUG = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False


...
```

Comment: So local_settings.py is just theose 3 lines, or my whole settings.py except that those 3 lines are different

Comment: @KovyJacob, local_settings.py is a part of settings.py. Set in local_settings.py only that you would to overwrite.

Comment: I have this code in my settings.py that forces my project to use https: 'SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True'. How do I reverse that in local_settings.py?

Comment: Thanks so much! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a folder called settings that include different python files for the base settings, the dev settings, the staging settings, the production settings and the test settings.

The base settings could be imported in dev, staging, production and test settings and then, you can set the value of existing variables (e.g. DEBUG) or define new variables.

The tree structure could be:

- {your-project-name}/

  - settings/

    - base.py
    - dev.py
    - staging.py
    - production.py
    - test.py

Then you can use them such as:

```sh
    $ python manage.py runserver --settings={your-project-name}.settings.dev
```

For the deployment, you could pass the proper settings through env variable (e.g. in case of docker images)